# PGSQL: match rows with same customer id with >90 days difference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a customer ID, a lead ID, a 'date active' and a date sold if relevant.
Goal: for each row that has a date sold, see if there is a row with a date active>90 days, and then return at least the most recent row, preferably both rows next to eachother in columns.

The lead ID is unique, one customer ID can have multiple lead IDs.

So far, I have the following result from this query:

```html
SELECT t1.customer_id, t1.lead_id,t1.date_sold,
  min(datediff(day,t2.date_active, t1.date_active )) AS date_dif
FROM data as  t1 
      LEFT JOIN data as t2
      ON t1.customer_id=t2.customer_id
      AND  t2.date_active < t1.date_active
WHERE t1.customer_id= 7157198 AND t1.client = 4444 
AND datediff(day,t2.date_active, t1.date_active )>90
GROUP BY t1.customer_id ,t1.lead_id,t1.date_sold
```

```html
sd_customer_id  sd_lead_id  sd_date_sold    date_dif
    7157198     7074874                     219
    7157198     7156775     2014-07-25      223
    7157198     5543700                     614
    7157198     3116760     2016-05-11      273
```

In the above example, I only want to show 7156775 and 3116760 because they had a date sold, together with the most recent previous date active (more than 90 days ago). But if I add this to the query I do not get data.
Also, I feel like I can optimize this by using the LATERAL join, but I did not succeed in it. Any tips?
Raw data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/26313

Comment: Is this really [tag:postgresql]? It seems not, because that make of table server doesn't have `DATEDIFF()`. Please [edit] your tags.

Comment: I am using postgres: http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff#:~:text=DATEDIFF%20returnes%20the%20number%20of,decimal%20part%20after%20the%20division

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above example, I only want to show 7156775 and 3116760 because they had a date sold

`INNER JOIN data as t2` or `WHERE sd_date_sold IS NOT NULL`

> Also, I feel like I can optimize this by using the LATERAL join, but I did not succeed in it

SQL optimization should start with `EXPLAIN <query>`

Comment: thanks, when i add "WHERE sd_date_sold IS NOT NULL" the query does not return any data

Comment: `"date_sold" varchar(10)` -> `select * from Table1 where date_sold <> 'nan';`

Is this really the correct type?

Comment: you are right, that was the issue. i had to add WHERE t1.is_sold = 1  thank you!